# How to await on threaded callback?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using a multi-threaded library that does not use `async`, but rather uses traditional threads and callbacks.

```
var connection = new SomeLib();
connection.OnConnected += (x) => { /* This is called from separate thread */ }
connection.Connect();
```

I am calling this code from an `async` function, like so:

```
public async Task<Boolean> MyFunc()
{
    var connection = new SomeLib();
    connection.OnConnected += (x) => { /* This is called from separate thread */ }
    connection.Connect();

    // ...

    // Need to return after OnConnected has been fired. 
    return true;
}
```

How can I use `await` to have my function "wait" for the `OnConnected` callback to be called?

Comment: What string are you trying to return? It feels like the first thing to do is write a `ConnectAsync` method (or possibly extension method) which might use a `TaskCompletionSource` as a reasonably simple way of tracking this.

Comment: The string is unimportant. This is just a toy example. What do you mean by writing a ConnectAsync method? I should mention that I cannot change the sources of the library I'm using.

Comment: @JonSkeet Am sorry, I'll remove my comment

Comment: Basically as per Shahar's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work for EventHandler<> type events - but you can easily adjust them to work for different signature delegates.. First, the helper function (EventToATaskAsync) which takes an adder and remover delegates to set/unset the event:

Note that the downside of using this mechanism is that you need to write an extension method per wrapped async operation.

```
public static Task<A> EventToTaskAsync<A>(Action<EventHandler<A>> adder, Action<EventHandler<A>> remover)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<A> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<A>();
    EventHandler<A> onComplete = null;
    onComplete = (s, e) =>
    {
        remover(onComplete);
        tcs.SetResult(e);
    };
    adder(onComplete);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then, I usually wrap it with an extension call to add the Task functionality to the existing class. In the following example, I am adding BeginAsync to a storyboard (but you can do that to pretty much anything that uses the event mechanism):

```
    public static Task BeginAsync(this Storyboard storyboard)
    {
        return EventToTaskAsync<object>(
                e => { storyboard.Completed += e; storyboard.Begin(); },
                e => storyboard.Completed -= e);
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a wait handle. First define an AutoResetEvent:

```
private waitForConnect = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

In the OnConnected handler, trigger the handle:

```
waitForConnect.Set();
```

In the function that calls connect, wait for the handle to trigger:

```
connection.Connect();
waitForConnect.WaitOne(); // This will sleep the thread until connected
```

Comment: The whole point of asynchronous methods (whether callback-style or `async`-`await`) is that they *don't block*. So I think doing this doesn't make any sense.